# Spark Streaming using Kinesis doesn't work if shard checkpoints exist in DynamoDB

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kcl

This was cross-posted in [SPARK-22685](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-22685).

**TL;DR** – If shard checkpoints don't exist in DynamoDB (== completely fresh), Spark Streaming application reading from Kinesis works flawlessly. However, if the checkpoints exist (e.g. due to app restart), it fails most of the times.

---

The app uses **Spark Streaming 2.2.0** and **spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.11**. 
When starting the app with checkpointed shard data (written by KCL to DynamoDB), after a few successful batches (number varies), this is what I can see in the logs:

First, **Leases are lost**:

```
17/12/01 05:16:50 INFO LeaseRenewer: Worker 10.0.182.119:9781acd5-6cb3-4a39-a235-46f1254eb885 lost lease with key shardId-000000000515
```

Then in random order: **Can't update checkpoint - instance doesn't hold the lease for this shard** and **com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: The target server failed to respond** follow, bringing down the whole app in a few batches:

```
17/12/01 05:17:10 ERROR ProcessTask: ShardId shardId-000000000394: Caught exception:
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: The target server failed to respond
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1069)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1035)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:742)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:716)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.doInvoke(AmazonKinesisClient.java:1948)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.invoke(AmazonKinesisClient.java:1924)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.executeGetRecords(AmazonKinesisClient.java:969)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.getRecords(AmazonKinesisClient.java:945)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.proxies.KinesisProxy.get(KinesisProxy.java:156)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.proxies.MetricsCollectingKinesisProxyDecorator.get(MetricsCollectingKinesisProxyDecorator.java:74)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.KinesisDataFetcher.getRecords(KinesisDataFetcher.java:68)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.ProcessTask.getRecordsResultAndRecordMillisBehindLatest(ProcessTask.java:291)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.ProcessTask.getRecordsResult(ProcessTask.java:256)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.ProcessTask.call(ProcessTask.java:127)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.MetricsCollectingTaskDecorator.call(MetricsCollectingTaskDecorator.java:49)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.MetricsCollectingTaskDecorator.call(MetricsCollectingTaskDecorator.java:24)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
  Caused by: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:143)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:261)
        at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:165)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:167)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:272)
        at com.amazonaws.http.protocol.SdkHttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(SdkHttpRequestExecutor.java:82)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:124)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:271)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
        at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1190)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1030)
        ... 22 more
```

and

```
17/12/01 05:20:59 ERROR KinesisRecordProcessor: ShutdownException:  Caught shutdown exception, skipping checkpoint.
com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.exceptions.ShutdownException: Can't update checkpoint - instance doesn't hold the lease for this shard
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.KinesisClientLibLeaseCoordinator.setCheckpoint(KinesisClientLibLeaseCoordinator.java:173)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.RecordProcessorCheckpointer.advancePosition(RecordProcessorCheckpointer.java:216)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.RecordProcessorCheckpointer.checkpoint(RecordProcessorCheckpointer.java:137)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.RecordProcessorCheckpointer.checkpoint(RecordProcessorCheckpointer.java:103)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisCheckpointer$$anonfun$checkpoint$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(KinesisCheckpointer.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisCheckpointer$$anonfun$checkpoint$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(KinesisCheckpointer.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisCheckpointer$$anonfun$checkpoint$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(KinesisCheckpointer.scala:94)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisRecordProcessor$.retryRandom(KinesisRecordProcessor.scala:158)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisCheckpointer$$anonfun$checkpoint$1.apply(KinesisCheckpointer.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisCheckpointer$$anonfun$checkpoint$1.apply(KinesisCheckpointer.scala:88)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisCheckpointer.checkpoint(KinesisCheckpointer.scala:88)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisCheckpointer.org$apache$spark$streaming$kinesis$KinesisCheckpointer$$checkpointAll(KinesisCheckpointer.scala:116)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisCheckpointer$$anonfun$1.apply$mcVJ$sp(KinesisCheckpointer.scala:130)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.util.RecurringTimer.triggerActionForNextInterval(RecurringTimer.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.util.RecurringTimer.org$apache$spark$streaming$util$RecurringTimer$$loop(RecurringTimer.scala:106)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.util.RecurringTimer$$anon$1.run(RecurringTimer.scala:29)
```

Right now, the workaround is to go and delete all the checkpoint data of all shards from DynamoDB so that the app starts from the `InitialPositionInStream.LATEST`. Obviously, the downside of that is that checkpoint information is not used at all, and data is lost.

I may have missed something obvious, so any help would be appreciated.